# Как дать понять питону, что если строка является 'null', то ее пробивать нельзя?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mysql, pymysql

Никак не могу понять одной вещи - как попросить питон НЕ пробивать строки без значения?

Ошибочный код:

```py
cur = await conn.cursor()
teled = message.from_user.id
sql = "SELECT teleid FROM users WHERE teleid=(%s)"
id = teled
await cur.execute(sql, (id))
r = await cur.fetchone()
print(r)
a = r
d = "".join(c for c in a if c.isalnum()) #<---- тут и появляется ошибка. Этот метод необходим для удаления скобок, которые ставит pymysql при обычном fetchone
```

Из-за того, что данные о новых юзерах не всегда имеется, появляется данная ошибка. Этот код нужен чтобы проверять есть если человек в базе данных. Если нет - он приступает к фрагменту занесения в бд. И при проверке появляется следующее:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isalnum'

Буду благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: Не могли бы вы перевести вопрос на русский? что такое "пробивать строку"?

Comment: `... if c is not None and c.isalnum() ...`